# React Admin - Handle data when API response is not found

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using React Admin and [Reqres](https://reqres.in/) for my REST api.

I'm struggling with the create action.

The problem is that the API not maintain the new element created, so when I made a POST action the api response with the new record, for ex:

```
{ 
 "first_name":"John",
 "last_name":"Doe",
 "email":"jdoe@mail.com",
 "id":"115",
 "createdAt":"2019-11-26T21:36:40.165Z"
}
```

But after that, by default React Admin redirects to edit page, show me new data and then make a `getOne` call with the id of the response, but because the API didn't save my new element, I get a 404 when React Admin do a `GET` to `https://reqres.in/api/users/115`.

What I want to ask if it is possible to store and get that temporary data and don't make the `getOne` call to avoid the error? Also how can I list the users with the new users? Because when the React admin call the `getList` that new element won't be on that list.

I have the basic for the data provider:

```
create: (resource, params) => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
}).then(({ json }) => ({
  data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
})),

getOne: (resource, params) => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`).then(({ json }) => ({
  data: json.data,
})),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand: your API answers to the POST with an OK response, but a subsequent GET call on the same resource identifier does not return the record? If that's the case, your API is not RESTful, and react-admin may not be adapted to your use case.

I see 2 possible workarounds:

1. In the `Create` component, add the `redirect="list"` prop to redirect to the list rather than the detail view. That way, the interface won't break - even though the new record will quickly appear (optimistic rendering) then disappear (once the response from the GET request arrives without the new record). You can also disable optimistic rendering by setting `undoable=false`, that will remove the flickering
2. In your `dataProvider.create()` (or `CREATE` in react-admin 2.x), don't return immediately after the API response arrives. Instead, ping the server every x seconds to see if the post is finally visible to a GET request, and only then your dataProvider Promise should return